# Python Complex if-else Problem with os module

Tags: python

I tried to write a script that will see for changes in a folder (any new files added, or files deleted or any updates ) and if there is change its should print "folder -changed" else print "not changed"

I write this code:

```
import os
mydir = os.getcwd() + '/testdir'
file_list = os.listdir(mydir)
num_list = len(file_list)

while True:
    if len(file_list) != num_list:
        print('Folder Changed')
    else:
        print('Folder Not Changed')
```

I need to see whenever a file added or deleted from a directory, the should print my string.

Can anyone please write me a code for this?

Much Appreciated!!

Comment: The values of `file_list` and `num_list` do not update themselves. You have to call `os.listdir` in each iteration of the loop to see if the list of files has changed.

Comment: An OS-specific solution like `inotify` would probably be better though; it does't require a busy loop. Instead, you script will block until the OS informs you that a file was added to (or deleted from, or modified in, or whatever you want to actually watch for) the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to compare the current scan with the previous one.

```
import os
import time

dir_to_scan = os.path.join('.', 'testdir')
current_file_list = os.listdir(dir_to_scan)

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    temp = os.listdir(dir_to_scan)
    if len(temp) != len(current_file_list):
        print('The number of files in folder was changed')
    else:
        print('The number of files in folder was NOT changed')
    current_file_list = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the list in loop and save it to `old_list` if it changed

```
import os, time
mydir = os.getcwd() + '/testdir'
old_list = len(os.listdir(mydir))
new_list = 0

while True:
    new_list = len(os.listdir(mydir))
    if old_list != new_list:
        old_list = new_list
        print('Folder Changed')
    else:
        print('Folder Not Changed')
    time.sleep(1)
```